# ActionListener Problems in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I have been trying to fix my code for a few hours and I still can't get rid of this error. In the code below, `One.addActionListener(this)` and `Two.addActionListener(this)` both have red lines under `this` saying 'Cannot use this in a static context'. Please help me out if you can. Thanks!

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.event.WindowListener;    
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class TheMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener {

        int input1 = 0;
        int input2 = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TheMain main = new TheMain();
            JButton One = new JButton("1");
            One.setSize(10, 10);
            One.addActionListener(this);    
            JButton Two = new JButton("2");
            Two.setSize(10, 10);
            Two.addActionListener(this);    
    }

    public TheMain(){
    JButton One = new JButton("1");
    One.setSize(10, 10);
    One.addActionListener(this);            

    JButton Two = new JButton("2");
    Two.setSize(10, 10);
    Two.addActionListener(this);        

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("window");
    frame.setSize(200, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(One);
    frame.add(Two);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(input1 != 0){
            if(input2 != 0){
                System.out.println("Max 2 numbers!");
            }else{
                input2 = 1;
            }
        }else{
            input1 = 1;
        }           
    }

    public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e) {
        if(input1 != 0){
            if(input2 != 0){
                System.out.println("Max 2 numbers!");
            }else{
                input2 = 2;
            }
        }else{
            input1 = 2;
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Read more about Object-Oriented programming. `this` must refer to an instance of the current class where there is no instance in a static context.

Comment: Simply write `main` in place of `this`, since you already made a reference to the class, inside your `main` method :-)

Comment: You're already creating the buttons in the constructor so why are you creating them again? Your class extends JFrame so why are you creating a new JFrame to add the buttons to?

Comment: `frame` and `main` are instances of `JFrame` now, you using them both :-) Seems like you really need to visit [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a static method you can only use static variables or local variables, you can't use instance variables, and `this` represents a `TheMain` instance, so you can't use it in the `main` method, which is `static`. You should change

```
addActionListener(this);
```

to

```
addActionListener(main);
```

Comment: thanks, when I run this there is just one big 2 button but no 1 button. do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @user1952565 It's due to the layout manager. Read [How to use Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Ok i've solved that but both One and Two buttons are reffering to the same actionlister, How can I fix that?

Comment: In the `actionPerformed` method, you can use the event to determine which button generated the action. `if(e.getSource() == yourButton)` will return true if the object that fired the event was `yourButton`

Comment: It doesn't regocnize my button?

Comment: Your button must be declared as instance variable in order for this to work. You can use `e.getActionCommand().equals("stringinyourbutton")` which will also work, in this case you are comparing the string which is on the button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33782/discussion-between-user1952565-and-backslash)

Comment: only works with One button not two?
heres my code pastebin.com/A2xPuEAa

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `this` in a `static` method  (in your case `main` method). Because, `this` represents **current instance** of the class on which the method is getting executed.

Since `static` methods are such methods which can be invoked **without an instance**,  `this` doesn't always makes sense. So java gives compilation error `Cannot use this in a static context`

you should change your code to

```
One.addActionListener(main);
```

Since `main` is an already created instance

Comment: thanks, when I run this there is just one big 2 button but no 1 button. do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @user1952565 : Default Layout for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`, so when you wrote `frame.add(One)`, it is internally treated as `frame.add(One, BorderLayout.CENTER)`, hence you adding two components at the same location, which is not possible, since only one component can be added to any location, at any given time. So try this `frame.add(One, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); and frame.add(Two, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);` and then `frame.pack() and then frame.setVisible(true)`. Read [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Ok thanks i've solved that but both One and Two buttons are reffering to the same actionlister, How can I fix that?